# Please elaborate why this question was deleted.

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deletion, deleted-questions

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4599061/1020656 I asked this question some days ago and also got some clear answers.( though I didn't marked any answer at that time as accepted because on that day I could not understand). However I found that this question was deleted because it don't "meet community guidelines" and asks me to "show additional efforts, definitions" ,etc.

[image]

1-If you were at my situation and were to ask this question, what additional things would you have given?

2-If the question is well-written to be clear and also shows my effort (which I think it does) , then I want to ask that- Is it necessary for every question to expand anyhow the self's work to make it look bigger and prove the efforts and works, if instead it can be done in a simple or short way

Thanks very much.

Comment: 1&2 - I would include the work I did to arrive at the answer proposed.   A lot of mistakes in one's conclusion are discovered from a simple mistake in one's *process*; show only the result, we can't help.

Comment: You asked the question two weeks ago.  It was deleted seven days later. In the meantime you made no effort to improve the question, despite comments suggesting how.  So your question here was answered below your question.  That you refused to follow it, is on you.

Comment: You can undelete the question(unless a mod deleted it) and edit it to make it better(see hardmath's answer), so it can be reopened.

Comment: Have you read – and taken to heart – the information given at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question ?

Comment: Also, search for your question using (Approach0)[https://approach0.xyz] as well : I got [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795046). There's also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3794777). Search, honestly and nicely, and you will surely find what you need : without needing to wait for it.

Comment: @amWhy  But the only detail about my effort that can be expanded is to show the steps involved in differentiation. I directly did differentiation. The question was not about the solution of the problem asked which I already know or can find on google too but about the wrongness of the solution that I proposed. And I clearly expressed that what is that solution but in small words. Anyway, I'll expand it. Thanks.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I hadn't read it fully but by seeing the responses on various questions, I have an understanding that how the community works.

Comment: @bobeyt6 Yes thanks. I'll edit it today.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the body of your Question, which you have copied above, it is impossible to understand what the problem is about.  You have posed the problem essentially in the title (not copied above).

This is a tempting shortcut for many new users, so don't take it as a personal criticism.  But we want the body of the Question to have a self-contained problem statement.

If you were to incorporate the problem statement into the body, then it would be natural to show some (brief) details of your calculation.  I'd be inclined to vote to undelete once the body of the Question were expanded in these ways.

Comment: Thanks. I did not take it as personal. But the only detail about my effort that can be expanded is to show the steps involved in differentiation. I directly did differentiation. The question was not about the solution of the problem asked which I already know or can find on google too but about the wrongness of the solution that I proposed. And I clearly expressed that what is that solution but in small words. Anyway, I'll expand it. Thanks.

Comment: If you really want an Answer about the wrongness of [your[ solution, you should bring the problem statement from the title into the body of your Question.  The mistake is evidently already made when you jumped into differentiating both sides.  E.g. $x=1$ has a unique solution, but differentiating both sides gives $1 = 0$ (contradiction).